# Embedded list - how to?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

```
@Entity
data class Products(
        val id:String,
        val title: String,
        val description: String,
        val imgUrl: String,
        val  usageRules : List<String>,  //what happens here?
)
```

i am playing around with ROOM for android and most of the examples i have seen does not explain how you would create a Entity table that has a arrayList within it.

There is  @Embedded which seems to only nest another object but i am trying to nest a LIST of objects called usageRules

Do i need to create a seperate Usage Rule table? The thing is, each usage rule can be included on multiple products above and also a product can have multiple usage rules defined so it is a many to many relationship.

Is this possible with ROOM?

I know that in Realm i can simply convert the UsageRule List<> to a RealmList<>. is there an equivalent in ROOM?

Another alternative is that because it is just a lis of strings. i could simply create a new table entity field called allUsage that stores all the usageRules on a particular product with a seperator and then later when i want to construct the data object again from ROOM i can grab its contents by doing allUsage.Split(..)

Still would rather do it another way as i may come across a scenarionwhere the usageRules are not just a list of strings but a list of objects....

Answer (score 0):

Try using ArrayList:-

```
@Entity
data class Products(
        val id:String,
        val title: String,
        val description: String,
        val imgUrl: String,
        val  usageRules : ArrayList<String>,  //what happens here?
)
```

Need to use Convertors for this:-

```
class Converters {

    companion object {

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromString(value: String): ArrayList<String>? {
            val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
            return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromArrayList(list: ArrayList<String>?): String {
            val gSon = Gson()
            return gSon.toJson(list)
        }
    }
}
```

And define Convertors Here:-

```
@Database(entities = [TableModel::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class RDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val tableDAO: TableDAO
}
```

One extra implementation needs:-

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

My code is perfectly working by this

Comment: The better way is to store the usage list in another table with a foreign key. That's how I did it

Comment: Yea and it works. Gives you more control. The above is fine but doesn't give you much flexibility and what if the usage list is huge and needs pagenation